# WOEUSB is not showing my drive

Tags: boot, usb, windows, lubuntu, woeusb

Am trying to put windows 7 ISO files on my storage driver and boot it from the USB Drive and it not showing my letter in the WOEUSB Drive... I have been using MKUSB to it works but when it goes to install the Operating System it says it can't find the media and direct me to find it... I been installing windows 7 on this driver for a while and had no problem with it the last few days... This has happened to me before and it seems I have to delete the drive on a Windows Operating System to fix it... I don't understand am using GParted to format the drive to and formating it to an NTFS and putting a boot flag on it and when I transfer the ISO FILES to the drive I shut down my PC and I go into the Boot Section and Press USB Boot Option and it says there NO BOOTABLE DEVICE!!! am like I put a BOOT FLAG on it so I have no idea what am doing wrong... I hope anyone can try to help me... Am I doing anything wrong because I can't be always right or am I like forgetting to do something because I understand people make mistakes on this stuff... But it kills me inside that I can't boot a Windows USB Media to just install Windows... Thanks Ubuntu TEAM <3 <3 <3

[image: img_GParted]

Comment: It might be easier to get a USB pendrive (I suggest 8 GB or larger) and try to make it a Windows install drive. It should work with both mkusb and woeusb. I think your problem is to find the target drive, the drive where you want to install the Windows installer. I mean that the tools or operating system underneath has problems to find the target drive. I think will work better with a USB pendrive. (When you have the iso file in the storage drive, you should not install into that drive, but into another drive.)

Comment: I don't understand it works with this 1 TB drive that I have it does not matter I have tried different ways to fix this problem... I have installed Windows 7 Multible times using this and I have used GParted to Format to NTFS and put Select in Manage Flags Boot... It work just find I don't understand why I am having so much problems I don't really think it a problem what kind of size it is...

Comment: I failed to explain, so I try again. Boot into an Ubuntu system on a first drive. Keep the Windows 7 iso file in a second drive or the first drive. Install the Windows installer into another drive (not the one you booted into and not the one where you have the iso file). Boot into the Windows 7 installer and select the target drive and install Windows into that drive. The target drive should not be the one that you booted into. It could be the old drive with Ubuntu or some other drive. It should be an internal drive (it is difficult to make Windows work from an external drive).

Comment: Ok I don't understand what you explaining you want me to first drive and keep files on the second drive how am I going to install Windows 7 on the other drive what program am I using you are not explaining to me could you show me some pictures...

Comment: If there is space enough on the first drive, you can keep the iso file in this first drive, that you have booted from :-) It means that you can install the Windows installer to any other drive. See these links with illustrations, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive and [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu/381560)

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not help but I did a similar thing to you, and couldn't see ANY bootable devices in my list. It wasn't that the program was missing my specific USB in the list for GUI, but like your image shows there are NO target devices to select. So I did something simple and tried to maximize the window by dragging the R corner and you wouldn't believe, the list was obscured because the default window size of woeUSB hides your target devices! resize the window: here's what I mean:

MAXIMIZED WINDOW

[image: img_Window]

So again, had no idea it wasn't going to be visible in default view *mind blown* - hope this helped

-Robert

Comment: Indeed, this was the solution for me as well. Alternatively, you could go to the command line and install it through that, i.e. supposing your drive is located at /dev/sdX, then you would write something along the lines of:

```sudo woeusb --target-filesystem NTFS --device /path/to/iso /dev/sdX```